# Apache 2.4 long delay before first response

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, lag

I've test server (Centos 7) in my local network with Apache 2.4. All works fine, but each time after about 1 hour of inactivity Apache responding with a lag about 4.8 sec. Next requests proccesed very fast (1-5 ms).

The lag appears AFTER connection (connect - 1ms, request sent - 1ms, waiting TTFB - 4.8s). The problem occurs regardless type of requested source (html page, html +php or just image). Another network applications works w/o lags.

IPv6 disabled. IP and port configured in httpd.conf:

---

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 192.168.0.100:80

KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
KeepAliveTimeout 300
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName 192.168.0.100:80

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Site"

<Directory "/Site/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/Site/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Site/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Site/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

---

[image: Chrome debugger]

Comment: You're likely going to get some answer that require a lot of work on your end to track this down. I highly suggest installing NewRelic and utilize their php profiler to get a better idea of what's going on - will save you some time.

Comment: Can you use `MaxKeepAliveRequests 100` and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: The lag is not related to keepalive. I've tested it with disabled keepalive - all same. Also it is not related to PHP - the lag appears even i just request only image file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made few tests and found the lag appears only on Windows(Win7) machines (PC and laptop). Mac, iphones and ipads works with server without lag. All devices in one subnet (simple DLink router). The lag is not related to connection type (laptop connected via wifi, PC via wire) and appears regardless of browser type. After one PC connected with lag and starts works fast, the another one connected with lag. So i think the problem somethere in windows network settings and not related to server.

**UPD:
The problem was in Kaspersky Antivirus. I disabled web-filter and now all works w/o lags.**

Comment: Do you mean the issue was entirely external to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen for a single or connection ? If after an hour you initiate a connection from client A, will client B have a fast response too or not ?

If not, then it's probably related to the keepalive timeout.
If yes, then it could be something related to caches

Comment: Thank you for question - i tried first send request from Mac - it works fine, w/o lags. It seams the problem only in Win PC. Another devices (mac, smartphones and tablets) works with server w/o lags. I will test more times.